# Type 'Any' has no subscript memebers

Tags: swift

When i converted to swift 3 , its saying type any has no subscript memebers.

```
let dataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as! AnyObject?
```

Ihave tried many possiblities but didn't worked.

Comment: Is none of this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift3%5DType+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members ? or this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Type+%27Any%27+has+no+subscript+members ?

Comment: nop , i have tried many

Comment: what is `dataDictionary`

Comment: What is `dataDictionary`'s type?

Comment: @user2702179 You need to specify the type of `dataDictionary` to compiler. like `if let result = dataDictionary as? [String:Any]` then use subscript with result.

Comment: i have tried this ,didn't worked

Comment: @user2702179 Initialize dataDictionry this way `if let dataDictionary = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? [String:Any] {
let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as? String
}
`

Comment: Worked Nirav ....

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)` is `Any` which doesn't allow subscripting. You have to use explicit type conversion to subscript. If you're trying to cast the data to `[String: Any]` you could do the following:

```
if let dataDictionary = dataDictionary as? [String: Any] {
    // dataDictionary["access_token"] as AnyObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONSerialization.jsonObject` throws an error so let catch it in a `do catch` block

```
    do {
        let dataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
        let accessToken = dataDictionary["access_token"] as! AnyObject
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```